# Revoke "subprocesses" tag synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

I just noticed that [subprocesses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocesses) is a synonym of [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess), where the latter refers specifically to the Python module [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). A case could probably be made for [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/subprocess) being unfairly coupled to Python, but for the moment I'm just concerned with the synonym. "subprocesses" clearly doesn't refer to the Python module, and users of any language can have questions about subprocess-handling.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/synonyms

I believe this synonym should be removed. Thoughts?

Comment: Definitely not, it's just the plural form of the other tag, they mean the same thing.  There's no reason for the tag to be tied to Python, edit the tag wiki and use it more generically.